# How to use Dojo dgrid in jsp table?

Tags: dojo, dgrid, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid, dojo.gridx

I am trying to implement dojo dgrid in my existing jsp table. I tried the example give [here](http://dgrid.io/tutorials/0.4/hello_dgrid/), and it works, but the issue is I am using a table, and I want to generate my JSON data in a way that it stores in , so it's properly aligned. I also checked the [GridFromHTML](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v1.2.1/doc/components/core-components/GridFromHtml.md) and it's [test](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v1.2.1/test/GridFromHtml.html), but I couldn't understand how to generate the JSON data with tds.

Here is the table code:

```
<table id="grid">
<tr class="colhdg">
    <th><fmt:message key="Sequence"/></th>
    <th><fmt:message key="Description"/></th>
    <th><fmt:message key="Due Date"/></th>
    <th><fmt:message key="Action"/></th>
</tr>

<c:forEach var="rowItem" varStatus="lineInfo" items="${formBean.rowList}">

<%@ include file="/standardoddeven.jsp" %>

<tr class="<c:out value='${trClass}'/>">
    <td>
        <c:out value="${rowItem.instructionSequence}"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <c:out value="${rowItem.description}"/>
    </td>
            <td>
        <fmt:formatDate value="${rowItem.dueDate}" pattern='<%=session.getAttribute("DATEFORMAT").toString()%>'/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <bean:define name="rowItem" id="submitObject" type="instructions" />
        <c:if test="${formBean.allowedOptions.UiTaskInstructionsViewUpdateAllowed}" >
            <%@ include file="/standardupdatedeletebuttons.jsp" %>
        </c:if>
    </td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

EDIT1:

Wrote the code that works apart from the 'Update' button. Not sure how to add   the last  in jsp table code to the  loop in javascript dojo.

Here is my code that works for the rest:

```
require([ 'dgrid/Grid', 'dojo/domReady!' ], function (Grid) {
    var data = [
    <c:forEach var="rowItem" varStatus="lineInfo" items="${formBean.rowList}">
        { sequence: '${rowItem.instructionSequence}', description: '${rowItem.description}', dueDate: '<fmt:formatDate value="${rowItem.dueDate}" pattern='<%=session.getAttribute("DATEFORMAT").toString()%>'/>', update: 'Update' }${!lineInfo.last ? ',' : ''}
    </c:forEach>
    ];

    var grid = new Grid({
        columns: {
            sequence: 'Sequence',
            description: 'Description',
            dueDate: 'Due Date',
            update: 'Update'
        }
    }, 'grid');
    grid.renderArray(data);
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I think you should use a dstore to keep your data aligned, check this http://dgrid.io/tutorials/0.4/grids_and_stores/